# String to binary? Java

Tags: java, binary

I have to convert a String into binary code. My first task is it to put in some values for a "ipv4header" by user input.

The result looks like: `4-5-24-5-0-000-0-32-0-0-195.168.1.102-223.168.1.102`
which is not a problem and now I have to convert this result to binary.

Expected result should be: `0100 0101 00011000 0000000000000101 0000000000000000 000 000000000000000100000 00000000 0000000000000001 11000011101010000000000011100110 11011111101010000000000110100000`

Please help me.

Thanks.

Is it possible to convert directly from String to binary? When I try to convert the Strings to int and then to binary, the 0 at the beginning get lost

import java.util.Scanner;
public class IPv4Header {

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String version;
    String ihl = "5";
    String tos;
    String paketlaenge = "5";
    String kennung;
    String flags;
    String fragmentOffset;
    String ttl;
    String headerChecksum;
    String protokoll;
    String quellIP;
    String zielIP;

    //#######################
    //
    //#######################

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Bitte Version eingeben");
    version = sc.next();
    int versionInt = Integer.parseInt(version);
    System.out.println("Binärcode von " + version + " = " + Integer.toBinaryString(versionInt));

    System.out.println("Bitte TOS eingeben");
    tos = sc.next();
    int tosInt = Integer.parseInt(tos);
    System.out.println("Binärcode von " + tos + " = " + Integer.toBinaryString(tosInt));

    System.out.println("Bitte Kennung eingeben");
    kennung = sc.next();
    int kennungInt = Integer.parseInt(kennung);
    System.out.println("Binärcode von " + kennung + " = " + Integer.toBinaryString(kennungInt));

    System.out.println("Bitte Flags eingeben");
    flags = sc.next();
    int flagsInt = Integer.parseInt(flags);
    System.out.println("Binärcode von " + flags + " = " + Integer.toBinaryString(flagsInt));

    System.out.println("Bitte Fragment-Offset eingeben");
    fragmentOffset = sc.next();
    int fragmentOffsetInt = Integer.parseInt(fragmentOffset);
    System.out.println("Binärcode von " + fragmentOffset + " = " + Integer.toBinaryString(fragmentOffsetInt));

    System.out.println("Bitte TTL eingeben");
    ttl = sc.next();
    int ttlInt = Integer.parseInt(ttl);
    System.out.println("Binärcode von " + ttl + " = " + Integer.toBinaryString(ttlInt));

    System.out.println("Bitte Protokoll eingeben");
    protokoll = sc.next();
    int protokollInt = Integer.parseInt(protokoll);
    System.out.println("Binärcode von " + protokoll + " = " + Integer.toBinaryString(protokollInt));

    System.out.println("Bitte Header-Checksum eingeben");
    headerChecksum = sc.next();
    int headerChecksumInt = Integer.parseInt(headerChecksum);
    System.out.println("Binärcode von " + headerChecksum + " = " + Integer.toBinaryString(headerChecksumInt));

    System.out.println("Bitte Quell-IP-Adresse angeben");
    quellIP = sc.next();

    System.out.println("Bitte Ziel-IP angeben");
    zielIP = sc.next();

    int ihlInt = Integer.parseInt(ihl);
    int paketlaengeInt = Integer.parseInt(paketlaenge);

    System.out.println("Ausgabe: " + version + "-" + ihl + "-" + tos + "-"
            + paketlaenge + "-" + kennung + "-" + flags + "-" + fragmentOffset + "-" 
            + ttl + "-" + headerChecksum + "-" + protokoll + "-" + quellIP + "-" 
            + zielIP);

    }}
```

Comment: please edit the output or provide some details to correspond to tht input

Comment: Use `Integer.toBinaryString(int i)`. See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29)

Comment: Integer.toBinaryString(headerChecksumInt) I tried this but the output cuts off the 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing seems to jive between the Header Checksum and the 'Expected Result' which quite honestly I think has either typo's in it or is somewhat fictitious with what is related to the header checksum. The IP numbers for example are converted to 8-bit binary values then appended together to form a 32-bit binary number but the last 8 bits in each binary number within the so called 'Expected Result' does not match what is supplied in the Header Checksum string. This is minor in the scope of things and we'll get to that later.

Since you haven't provided the model used to establish the 'Expected Result' (as @nullpointer suggested you do) you will need to do this yourself.

Here is a small method You can use while you iterate through and split your Header Checksum string to create your binary string. You can supply whatever size of bits you want to your binary number to be (all it does is left pad with zeros):

```
private static String integerToBinaryString(int number, int bitSize) {
        String binary = (String)Integer.toString(number, 2);
        binary = String.format("%0" + bitSize + "d", Integer.valueOf(binary));
        return binary;
}
```

To get a 8-bit binary number string for the integer number of 5 you would do:

```
String binaryString = integerToBinary(5, 8);
System.out.println(binaryString);
```

Now, I don't know what the translation model might be for converting your Header Checksum into a binary string but here is a quick method I whipped up that produces an output which I think it is and I think it's pretty darn close:

```
public static String translateHeaderChecksum(String headerChecksum) {
    // Declare and initialize required variables
    // Tokenize the contents of the headerChecksum string
    // variable into an Array based on the dashes (-) within
    // the string.
    String[] tokens = headerChecksum.split("-");
    String binaryString = "";
    String binaryValue = ""; 

    // Interate through the tokens[] Array and carry out convertions
    // such as convert number strings to integer and then the integer
    // numbers to the desired binary strings. The switch/case within
    // the 'for loop' handles our tranlation model as to what we're
    // going to do with each each part of the header checksum string.
    // Remember, each of those parts are now contained within the 
    // tokens[] string Array.
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        int hcn = 0;
        // Convert the string number contained within the tokens[] Array
        // to integer so as to prep supply to the integerToBinaryString()
        // method.We only do elements 0 to 9 because elements 10 and 11
        // contain IP addresses and need to be handled separately. See 
        // case 11 & case 12 below).
        if (i >= 0 && i<=9) {
            hcn =  Integer.valueOf(tokens[i]);
        }

        // Handle each header checksum value, convert to binary
        // and ensure proper bit count.
        switch (i+1) {
            case 1: case 2: 
                binaryValue = integerToBinaryString(hcn,4);
                break;
            case 3:
                binaryValue = integerToBinaryString(hcn,8);
                break;
            case 4: case 5:
                binaryValue = integerToBinaryString(hcn,16);
                break;
            case 6:
                binaryValue = String.format("%0" + 3 + "d", hcn);
                break;
            case 7: 
                binaryValue = integerToBinaryString(hcn,15);
                break;
            case 8:
                binaryValue = binaryValue + integerToBinaryString(hcn,4);
                break;
            case 9: 
                binaryValue = integerToBinaryString(hcn,8);
                break;
            case 10:
                binaryValue = integerToBinaryString(hcn,16);
                break;
            case 11: case 12:
                // Handle the two IP addresses located at the end of
                // Header Checksum string. Place each number of the IP 
                // into a string Array variable named ipTokens[] but 
                // first we need to get rid of the periods since split()
                // doesn't play well with them, We'll change them with
                // commas (,).
                tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace('.',',');
                String[] ipTok = tokens[i].split(",");
                // Iterate through each number of the IP address we're
                // currently working on and convert it to a binary string.
                for (int j = 0; j < ipTok.length; j++) {
                    // Since the our final two binary number strings are 
                    // in fact each IP address number converted to a 8-bit
                    // binary number and all pushed together (appeneded) to
                    // one another to form a 32-bit binary number, we do that
                    // here.
                    binaryValue = binaryValue + integerToBinaryString(Integer.valueOf(ipTok[j]),8);
                }
                break;
        }

        // Here we compile our final binary string. For every
        // interation we append our determined binary number
        // strings to it.
        // We skip the application of case 7 to our final binary
        // string because case 8 is appended to it (see case 8).
        if ((i + 1) != 7) {
            binaryString+= " " + binaryValue;
            binaryValue = "";
        }
    }
    // Trim off any leading or trailing spaces we had 
    // applied to the final binary string.
    binaryString = binaryString.trim();

    // Return our final binary string.
    return binaryString;
}
```

Here is a quick example of you can use the **translateHeaderChecksum()** method:

```
String headerChecksum = "4-5-24-5-0-000-0-32-0-0-195.168.1.102-223.168.1.102";
System.out.println(translateHeaderChecksum(headerChecksum));
```

Here is the Header Checksum string you provided:

> 4-5-24-5-0-000-0-32-0-0-195.168.1.102-223.168.1.102

Here is the 'Expected Result' you provided which I think is flawed and I'll tell you why later on:

> 0100 0101 00011000 0000000000000101 0000000000000000 000
>   000000000000000100000 00000000 0000000000000001
>   11000011101010000000000011100110 11011111101010000000000110100000

Now, if you take your provided Header Checksum string and run it through the **translateHeaderChecksum()** method I just provided you will get:

> 0100 0101 00011000 0000000000000101 0000000000000000 000
>   000000000000000100000 00000000 0000000000000000
>   11000011101010000000000101100110 11011111101010000000000101100110

You will notice a differences within the last three binary numbers. Let's start with the 3rd from end 16-bit binary number of 0000000000000001. Is this a typo because for the life of me I just don't know how you get a 1 out of zeros supplied within the Header Checksum string.

The last two 32-bit binary numbers are derived from the IP Addresses located at the end of the Header Checksum string and it's only the last 8 bits in both of those numbers that just does not match with what is supplied within the Header Checksum string thus, the 'Expected Result' is flawed.

Let's take the 2nd from last 32-bit binary number first. The last 8 bits within the 'Expected Result' is 01100110 which translated to decimal is 230, not the 102 as specified within the Header Checksum string from the IP 195.168.1.102. The **translateHeaderChecksum()** method output however did produce the proper 8 bits of 01100110.

Now let's take the last 32-bit binary number. The last 8 bits within the 'Expected Result' is 10100000 which translated to decimal is 160, not the 102 as specified within the Header Checksum string from the IP 223.168.1.102. The **translateHeaderChecksum()** method output however did produce the proper 8 bits of 01100110.

If there is to be something to compare to then it sure would be nice if it were at least somewhat accurate.

Anyways Jade...I hope this helps you somewhat.